# Is there any generic date format available?

Tags: java, javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am using format `"yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss"` in one script and uses that in my script.
If I modify the region (timezone) , date in system, it breaks onto this format.

Is there any generic date format which always works no matter how the system clock is set the time/ timezone with ?

Comment: ISO 8601 is such a standard?

Comment: No, it isn't such generic format. A date can be represented in many ways. There is a standard format but not all *dates* should follow it.

Comment: @Prashant2329 I have edited your question and removed the unnecessary capitalization of words.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Based on local timezone, can I set the date format ? Is it possible ?

Comment: ISO 8601 is what you're looking for. It standardizes how dates are represented, providing predictable locations for each component.

Comment: @fge looks like OP's asking on how to format the data provided to whatever method he/she uses, it has a different format if the region changes, so I think OP doesn't have control on how the format of the incoming data will come, but only handle the format to try to convert the string into a Date.

Comment: No. I want to set the format so that my script should never fail, no matter what the current date, time or timezone is ... That's it

Comment: I am using new Date() class in java.util library. So, I just want to set the format which should never fail... Is that possible ? Any method which would fetch format for the system on which the script running and then set the format for the date ?????????????????

Comment: @ssube When using ISO 8601 for new Date().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD")  throws an exception 'ILLEGAL CHARACTER EXCEPTION Y'

Comment: @Prashant2329 , keep your date in "long" format and display using Calendar/local/TZ format you want -- show your actual code -- how are you getting the date, how it is used in your program, than we can address exact issue

Comment: new Date().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD") is the stmt throwing exception... If I set format to "yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", it works on my system, but doesn't work on all systems...

Comment: THE new Date() class I am using is from java.util.Date

Comment: The java.util.TimeZone is not emulated class. Also, Using the emulated Date(java.util.Date/java.sql.Date) classes, you will have to convert the client's Date from the browser's timezone to some target timezone (GMT?). This will most likely be error prone  -- can you do this somehow on Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Question is unclear.

## No Magical Parsing Pattern

If you are asking for a magical parsing pattern that can handle any possible incoming textual representation of a date-time value, the answer is "No". The simple example of "1/2/12" proves this, as that might be January 2, February 1, or something else. You can make guesses and assumptions, but never be sure. Much discussed in many duplicate questions.

To be sure, you must know your incoming data.

## ISO 8601

If you are asking for a suggested pattern to format your own textual representations of date-time values, the standard ISO 8601 formats are the way to go. Read the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ`

Discussed many times in duplicate Questions.

The java.time framework has extended that string format by appending the proper time time name. Clever and useful, but not yet standard.

## UTC

Best practice for handling date-time is to use [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone on the back end.

Adjust to a time zone only in user-interface or exports when expected.

Discussed in many duplicate Questions.

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

Avoid the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome, flawed in design and implementation.

Instead use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). Both of these use ISO 8601 as their defaults in parsing/generating string representations of date-time values.

Example in Joda-Time 2.7…

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2015-01-02T12:34:56.789-02:00", DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Discussed in many duplicate Questions.

## Avoid Count-From-Epoch

The suggestion to track a count of milliseconds is misguided.

Such a count-from-epoch has no meaning to a human reader making debugging complicated and erroneous data invisible.

Which [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)? A [couple dozen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been used in various software systems.

Which size granularity of count? Various software systems use whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, or other.

[image]

Again, discussed in many duplicate Questions.